# Unable to edit subivided version of mesh object

Tags: objects, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, object-mode

I 'm new to Blender and recently I started creating objects by using *Edit Mode*.

1. Selected cube
2. Subdivided cube
3. Changed mode to *Edit Mode*
4. Now I can't edit the object face

Comment: hello, please show some screenshots or even share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi, i've uploaded the file can you check if you can see it?

Comment: you need to share the link it will give you (in the URL field)  ;)

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/87103a449d8c452486c245cefd56228c

Comment: Can you check now as i have shared the URL link?

Answer (score 2):

You have not really subdivided the cube, you have given it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, which modify the object only virtually (or visually) as long as it is not applied.

What you see in *Edit* mode is the object as affected by the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, not the real object, which is still a cube. *Subdivision Surface* modifier doesn't create real additional edges, it creates only virtual edges. If you unclick the *Edit Mode* option of the modifier it will display the mesh in *Edit* mode as it really is:

[image]

[image]

If you click on the *On Cage* option it will show you where the current vertices would be if you apply the modifier:

[image]

If you apply the modifier (click on the down arrow on the top of the modifier to display the dropdown panel and click *Apply*), here is the result, this time it has created real vertices and you can manipulate them, but it gives an object that is not as light as before, and not as easy to work with. If you plan to apply a modifier, sometimes it's good to duplicate the object before, to always keep a version with the modifier unapplied.

[image]

Comment: After clicking on on cage option what and where do I have to click next, please be precise as its my first week on blender. And sorry for the hassle I have caused you.

Comment: @Chris hey thanks for the +1, now I can tell you that I was not sorry at all  :))))

Comment: @Sanaula7, it depends on what you want to do, if you want to have a more dense topology, you can apply the modifier (on the top of the modifer, click on the down arrow button and choose Apply).

Comment: I applied the modifier by clicking on downward arrow, and there's option to apply and it worked. Thanks man really appreciate it. How do I give u credit for helping?

Comment: on the top left of my answer, you need to click on the check icon